# How to get a django template to pull information from two different models?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, mariadb

I am coding a basic django application that will show a table of current store sales, based off of information from a MariaDB database.

The data is entered into the database through a seperate process, so it isn't created in Django, it is just using a simple python script to load a csv file and parse it into an Insert query. There are two models in my code, Stores and ShowroomData. Showroomdata holds all of the records from the python script, however it does not hold any store information. I would like for it to be able to show all of the showroom data as well as the store's location title which is not stored in the ShowroomData model. I know I need to seperate models but can not figure out how to get them to link together.

```
class ShowroomData(models.Model):
    storeid = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # Field name made lowercase.
    date = models.DateField()  # Field name made lowercase.
    time = models.TimeField()  # Field name made lowercase.
    sales = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('storeid', 'date', 'time'),)
        db_table = 'showroomdata'


class Stores(models.Model):
    storeid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField()
```

I would like for it to be able to output a table like so:

StoreID - Location - Date - Time - Sales - Tax

Here is my WIP html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Trickle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Current Showroom Data</h1>

    {% if current_showroom %}

        <table>
            <thead>
              <th>Store Number</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Sales</th>
              <th>Tax</th>
            </thead>

            {% for store in current_showroom %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ store.storeid }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>




    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `storeid` field on the ShowroomData model of actually a foreign key. So you should declare it as such:

```
class ShowroomData(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey("Stores", db_column="storeid")
```

Now you can follow that fk in your template. Assuming `current_showroom` is a queryset of ShowroomData instances:

```
        {% for store in current_showroom %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ store.storeid }}</td>
            <td>{{ store.store.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```